# List unique values from one list that are not present in a range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that is formated like this:
[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv3G9.jpg)

The bottom half of the page is a database of all the interventions each student is assigned.

The top of the spreadsheet is a summary of which students are receiving an intervention. This part works properly for columns A|B|C, but not Column D.

For Column D (Not in A,B,C), I am looking for a way to compare the unique names in columns A|B|C to the list of names in the database at the bottom of the sheet, and then return the names that are in the database, but not in A|B|C. So, Column D in the picture should return StudentY and StudentZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this formula in D2:

```
=FILTER(A6:A,
REGEXMATCH(A6:A,
JOIN("|",TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(A2:C3&",")),","))))=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the current set of data, this should work:

```
=filter(A7:A12; not(regexmatch(B7:B12; "Intervention(A|B|C)")))
```

But I have a feeling that the 'names' of the intervention won't always start with 'Intervention' ?

Comment: Max Makhrov's answer is more flexible. Thanks though.